# Search results page - providing additional pre-filters in search results

Tags: filter, search-results, badge

### **Background**

We are looking into what is considered as a ‘top’ vacation rental property and how we can lets the users know this. We have a good idea of a criteria that goes into this.

### Challenge

We have also had some findings which summaries that putting another badge on a property listing won’t be all that impactful or trustworthy. Not to mention there is enough info already on the listings/search results page that we have (image, price, title etc.)

### Hypothesis

Im leaning towards a more invisible design - whenever a user goes to a listings/search results page, the first lot a results should already have the ‘top property’ criteria IN ADDITION to the search criteria they set. The only exception would be if it limits the search results too much.

### Example to my hypothesis

User inputs criteria in the searchbox (destination, dates, guests) —>
User is directed to results page based on their criteria —>
Search filter ALSO includes pre selected options such as wifi included, free cancellation option etc.

### Questions

- How much of a negative impact would it be if we provided a more
  pre-filtered results list?
- Is there any research to back this up or    suggest another
  alternative option?

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the users more control and don't apply filters they haven't set already. On the main page you can "suggest" properties but other than that, if the user has different criteria in mind you can not impose a property on them.

A good case study for this situation is AirBnB. They show everything available on minimal criteria (city and dates) and then suggest hosts that are "superhosts" then everybody else.

The user can than add the filter for only superhosts to be shown or not.